# Recursive Sierpinski's Triangle Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to draw Sierpinski's Triangle recursively in Java, but it doesn't work, though to me the logic seems fine. The base case is when the triangles are within 2 pixels of each other, hence the use of the Distance Formula.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Canvas;

public class Triangle extends Canvas implements Runnable
{
    private static final int WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 600;


public Triangle()
{
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}

public void paint( Graphics window )
{
    window.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    window.setFont(new Font("ARIAL",Font.BOLD,24));     
    window.drawString("Serpinski's Gasket", 25, 50);

    triangle(window, (WIDTH-10)/2, 20, WIDTH-40, HEIGHT-20, 40, HEIGHT-20, 4);
}

public void triangle(Graphics window, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3, int r)
{


    //if statement base case
        //midpoint = (x1 + x2 / 2), (y1 + y2/ 2)
        if(Math.sqrt((double)(Math.pow(x2-x1, 2)) + (double)(Math.pow(y2-y1, 2))) > 2)
        //if(r==0)
        {
            window.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);     
            window.drawLine(x2, y2, x3, y3);
            window.drawLine(x3, y3, x1, y1);
        }

        int xa, ya, xb, yb, xc, yc;   // make 3 new triangles by connecting the midpoints of
        xa = (x1 + x2) / 2;             //. the previous triangle 
        ya = (y1 + y2) / 2;
        xb = (x1 + x3) / 2;
        yb = (y1 + y3) / 2;
        xc = (x2 + x3) / 2;
        yc = (y2 + y3) / 2;


        triangle(window, x1, y1, xa, ya, xb, yb, r-1);   // recursively call the function using the 3 triangles
        triangle(window, xa, ya, x2, y2, xc, yc, r-1);
        triangle(window, xb, yb, xc, yc, x3, y3, r-1);

}

public void run()
{
    try{
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(3);    
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}
}
```

The Runner is

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FractalRunner extends JFrame
{
    private static final int WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 600;

public FractalRunner()
{
    super("Fractal Runner");

    setSize(WIDTH+40,HEIGHT+40);

    getContentPane().add(new Triangle());   

    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main( String args[] )
{
    FractalRunner run = new FractalRunner();
}
}
```

To me this should work but it causes a runtime/StackOverFlow error that I don't know how to correct. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the recursive calls to triangle, and the associated math, inside the conditional check on the separation.  Right now, it will always call it and therefore you get the stack overflow.

Comment: Why does it always call it though? It's supposed to stop when the distance between triangles gets to less than 2 px

Comment: But the calls are not within the conditional - so they are always made.  Instead move the closing paren on the if's block to the end of the function so that the recursive calls are subject to the same check.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I wasn't sure how to do that. Did it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your base case might not be working properly- what if the distance between two triangles is never two pixels? say we star with y1 and x1 being 0 and 200. their midpoint would be 100, then 50, 25, 12, 6, 3, 1<--- never hits the 2 pixel base case...

Answer (score 0):

"StdDraw" was taken from [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/):

```
public class Sierpinski {

    public static void sierpinski(int n) {
        sierpinski(n, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    public static void sierpinski(int n, double x, double y, double size) {

        if (n == 0) return;

        //compute triangle points
        double x0 = x;
        double y0 = y;
        double x1 = x0 + size;
        double y1 = y0;
        double x2 = x0 + size / 2;
        double y2 = y0 + (Math.sqrt(3)) * size / 2;

        // draw the triangle        
        StdDraw.line(x0, y0, x1, y1);
        StdDraw.line(x0, y0, x2, y2);
        StdDraw.line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        StdDraw.show(100);

        //recursive calls
        sierpinski(n-1, x0, y0, size / 2);
        sierpinski(n-1, (x0 + x1) / 2, (y0 + y1) / 2, size / 2);
        sierpinski(n-1, (x0 + x2) / 2, (y0 + y2) / 2, size / 2);
    }

    // read in a command-line argument n and plot an order Sierpinski Triangle
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.005);
        sierpinski(n);
    }
}
```

Guy